# Animating Relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got following XML structure of my screen. I want my Relative Layout with id journeyLandingView to get slide up upon click on some button and show view RelativeLayout with id journeyRootView which will slide up from bottom since journeyLandingView have Fill_Parent set as height and width so journeyRootView must be below journeyLandingView that is covering the whole screen. How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/journeyLandingView">   
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/journeyRootView"
        android:background="@drawable/root_layer">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using RelativeLAYOUT instead of LINEARLAYOUT as a parent element and than used following code to animate.

```
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -1*Methods.screenHeight(this));   
             slide.setDuration(1000);   
             slide.setFillAfter(true);   
             journeyLandingView.startAnimation(slide); 
             slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, Methods.screenHeight(this), 0);   
             slide.setDuration(1000);   
             slide.setFillAfter(true);   
             journeyRootView.startAnimation(slide);

public static int screenHeight(Context ctx) {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) ctx).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);                 
        return displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    }
```

Comment: nice one can you say how to do for slide left out and slide right in.You have done for top to bottom

Answer (score 8):

I belive the kind of animation you want can be achieved using a ViewFlipper.

You could put your RelativeLayouts into a ViewFlipper, and set the in and out animations on the ViewFlipper programatically.

Sample code:

xml (layout):

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:text="click me"
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                />
            <ViewFlipper 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
                >
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/journeyLandingView"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                >  
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/journeyRootView"
                android:background="#FFA500"
                >

            </RelativeLayout>
            </ViewFlipper>        
        </LinearLayout>
```

java (Activity):

```
    ViewFlipper vflipper;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        vflipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        vflipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        vflipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        vflipper.showNext();
    }
```

You would be using a custom animation instead of the "android.R.anim.slide_in_left" and "android.R.anim.slide_out_right" i've used in the example code at lines:

```
        vflipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        vflipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

However, i'm not really good at making custom animations, so i'm leaving that to yourself.
Really hope this helped :-)