# Animating a relative layout to move down/up like Snack Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

So I have been trying to animate a smaller relative layout down/up from another relative layout.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293907/animating-relativelayout) in hopes of trying to solve my problem. I was thinking of doing something like the snack bar, but I still would want to add an image to it, which may be a problem completely on its own. Ideas? 
Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_log_in"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.esole.lithouse.SignUp"
android:background="#E6E6E6">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/logInBar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:title="Log In" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:id="@+id/editTextUsernameOrEmail"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logInBar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="username or email " />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/passwordLogIn"
    android:hint="password "
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextUsernameOrEmail" />

<Button
    android:text="Log In"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LogIn"
    android:layout_above="@+id/statusIndicator"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="67dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:background="#006D6D"
    android:id="@+id/statusIndicator"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/indicatorStatusLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="test "
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="24sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="67dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/refresh"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is some of the code I have tried to use:

```
slideInAndOut = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.statusIndicator);
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -slideInAndOut.getHeight());
slide.setDuration(1000);
slide.setFillAfter(true);
slideInAndOut.startAnimation(slide);
slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, slideInAndOut.getHeight(), 0);
slide.setDuration(1000);
slide.setFillAfter(true);
```

Comment: what happened when you try that ?

Comment: sorry for the delay, it was currently set to the bottom of the relative layout. So when I added that snippet of code to move it. it still didn't move. Which brought me here.

Comment: my answer will work ! but you better figure out what `Methods.` in original answer

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: yet i have a question is for you do you want to  make this really look like the snack bar appearing appear and disappear

Comment: It would be nice.

Comment: well then go with the Handler  but make sure you you use right values inted of my 100 which is hard coded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should use `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat` in your `imageView`

`TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)` are the paras he is using!

Second this **will work**

```
slideInAndOut = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.statusIndicator);
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -slideInAndOut.getHeight());
slide.setDuration(1000);
slide.setFillAfter(true);
slideInAndOut.startAnimation(slide);
slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100, 0); // seems you have a problem with 3rd param
slide.setDuration(1000);
slide.setFillAfter(true);
slideInAndOut.startAnimation(slide);
```

**----- Wait** you will see a code repetition there. Double check!

For only up this is enough!

```
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100, 0);
slide.setDuration(1000);
slide.setFillAfter(true);
slideInAndOut.startAnimation(slide);
```

To add more value I modified your code a bit.
(now this view will come up and again will go down if you only need one `TranslateAnimation` you dont need both!)

```
// goes up
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100,0 );
slide.setDuration(1000);
slide.setFillAfter(true);
slideInAndOut.startAnimation(slide);

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         // goes down
        TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,0,100);
        slide.setDuration(1000);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        slideInAndOut.startAnimation(slide);
    }
}, 3000);
```